# CloudKit record version control

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit, macos-sierra

I am comparing the version of a CKRecord, using `recordChangeTag`, where I saw the value changed from `n9` (2 chars) to `1c1` (3 chars) over time.

In [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord/1462195-recordchangetag):

> In your own code, you can use change tokens to distinguish between two
>   different versions of the same record.

I want to ask:

1. Is the string value in this field an incrementing one?
2. What is the right way to compare the order of the records?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question #2. What do you mean by "to compare the order of the records"? The `recordChangeTag` has nothing to do with record order. It is merely guaranteed to change when a new version of a record is saved.

Comment: I want to compare which record is the latest

Comment: But what two record versions are you comparing? If you are getting record changes using something like `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`, then the CKRecords that are returned from that operation are the "latest" ones in CloudKit - no need to compare recordChangeTags yourself. If you are handling conflicts on save, then you need to decide what conflict-resolution algorithm you are using, but you still should not be doing anything with the recordChangeTag besides a simple equality comparison between two records.

Comment: The recordChangeTag contents are not documented to follow any particular format. You should treat it as an opaque String value that is guaranteed to change when a record is changed, but has *no* guarantees as to how/what it will change to. You should not use the recordChangeTag to determine which record is newer - only that two records are *different* versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `recordChangeTag` system field is **changing** to another one when the record is updated. There is no description of how the string changes.
2. However, once you discover that the record has changed, you can compare value from another system field `modificationDate` of the new record to the one which you saved along with `recordChangeTag` of an old record.